# Question about the time needed for carb loading in bodybuilding

Tags: diet, bodybuilding, nutrition, carbohydrate, water

I am preparing for a photoshoot on Sunday, and have been depleting my carbohydrates and drinking a lot of water while doing glycogen depleting workouts this past week, as I see is often suggested online. This is supposed to culminate in cutting all water and loading carbs in order to make muscles appear as full as possible on the day of a show or photoshoot.

Where I run into confusion is on how long I am supposed to load my carbs before the shoot. Some people say one day before, some people say two, others say three! Which is correct?

I am also wondering about the carbs themselves, and whether or not I should avoid things like fat during this time. There are many types of carbs out there so, what sorts of carbs should I be loading with for an optimal effect?

Comment: This does not seem like it's on-topic for the site since it's about muscle appearance rather than fitness.

Comment: I agree with @SeanDuggan.  This is off-topic.  However, I can tell you from my past experience as a bodybuilder, that the response to carb-loading will be different for each person for various reasons.  If you've never tried carb loading, now is not the time to try.

Comment: I did a competitive bodybuilding show in fall 2019. The night before we had a cheeseburger and fries. The morning of, literally right right before getting on stage for our routine we had apple pie filing and almond butter. I was so Hingry I ate too much that morning and it made me bloat. So whatever you do. Just stay in moderation

Comment: I followed advice from [Paul Revelia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2OUGhyie-A) a couple times.  Unfortunately he states that it's very individualistic and he likes to carb up five days out to see how the body responds and then taper off. It doesn't sound like you have that much time, but maybe he can give you some helpful advice.